# How to write Makefile that traverses files in a directory

Tags: shell, makefile

Today I tried to write Makefile to traverse all files in a directory. I wrote in a Shell style like this,

```
for file in `find $(DEPLOY_PATH)/ -type l`; \
do \
  echo $(file); \
done
```

There are 9 link files, but when I run make, it printed 9 empty lines, without file name

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete `makefile`.

Comment: You are writing a shell script which is setting the shell variable `$file`, but you're referencing the make variable `$(file)`.  You should say `echo $$file` instead.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes，you are right！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(file)` refers to a **Makefile** variable. What you want is `$$file`:

```
$ cd "$(mktemp --directory)"
$ cat Makefile 
all:
    for file in *; \
    do \
        echo "$$file" || exit 1; \
    done
$ make
for file in *; \
do \
    echo "$file" || exit 1; \
done
Makefile
with spaces
```